# Configure godaddy SSL on custom server and Nginx

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to configure a `Godaddy certificate` on my server.
First one, I download two files:
`generated-private-key.txt` and `generated-csr.txt`

The content of the file is:

**generated-private-key.txt**

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MII/*CONTENT*ofF
/****MORE LINES***/
aC/*CONENTE*/8NDCLK8=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**generated-private-key.txt**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIC/*CONTENT*/0B
/*CONTENT*/
3UA/*CONTENT*/JhWHIf4A==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

And a `zip file` with three files: 
 - 13138a196fba51ea.crt
 - 13138a196fba51ea.pem
 - gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

Ok. What am I doing right now.
Using `scp` I copied the content of `generated-private-key.txt` into my server with the name `private.key` and the content of my `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` into my server with the name `cert.crt`.

When I test them on my server I get:

`$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in cert.crt -modulus`
Appears signature and important configuration without errors.

`openssl rsa -noout -text -in private.key -modulus`
Appears signature and important configuration without errors.

But at the moment to check the integrity, I get:
`$ openssl s_server -cert cert.crt -key private.key`
I get this error:

> Using default temp DH parameters error setting private key
>   140667192645520:error:0B080074:x509 certificate
>   routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:341:

What am I doing wrong? and how I can configure in the right way my certificate and private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same issue with GoDaddy certificates.

Here is what I did ( in case others encounter this ) :

1. Convert the private key file to ASCII

> ```
> iconv -c -f UTF8 -t ASCII generated-private-key.txt > private.key
> ```

2. Copy the pem file

> ```
> cat <domain>/<pem file name>.pem > cert.pem ( 13138a196fba51ea.pem in your case )
> ```

3. Added the private key contents to cert file

> ```
> cat private.key >> cert.pem
> ```

4. Verify the files

> ```
> openssl rsa -noout -text -in private.key -modulus
> openssl x509 -noout -text -in cert.pem -modulus
> ```

This worked for me

This helped in fixing

> (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)

and

> 140667192645520:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:341: